# php laravel add checkbox to existing datatable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, datatables

I am trying to add the checkbox for a datatable. The datatable is connected with the mysql database. I want to add a checkbox column for each datatable on the page.
Here is my markup in blade file:

```
 <table class="display" width="100%" id="test-table">
             <x-thead :headers="Constants:TESTHEADER"></x-thead>
    </table>
```

'TESTHEADERS' is a list that contains the column name of the datatable.
here is the script part:

```
<script>
        var dt; 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            renderDt();
        });

     
        function renderDt(){
            dt = $('#test-table').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json, xhr ) {
                $("#loadingAnimation").hide();
            }).DataTable({
                
                ajax:{
                    url:"/crm-lead/ajaxGetList",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"JSON",
                    data: {
                        date: $('#date').val()
                    }
                },
                columns:[
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'created_at'},
                    {data: 'contact_name'},
                    {data: 'company_name'},
                    {data: 'contact_phone'},
                    {data: 'contact_email'},
                    {data: 'lead_source'},
                ],
                order: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                serverSide:true,
                lengthMenu: [ 10, 15, 50, 100 ],
            });
        }
</script>
```

can you please help me to figure it out? many thx!